# Chatbot for XMPP based UC system

Tags: xmpp, chatbot

I've developed my own chat application using XMPP protocol, in this application I want to make a bot user for auto reply.So any suggested open source chat bot framework which can be used for it and what should be the best bot based application architecture?

Comment: It would help if you have a target language in mind. There are many client libraries and frameworks for a variety of languages.

Comment: I am using java .Any suggested framework and tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, many people use [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/). I'd recommend checking that out.

Comment: I used openfire base code for my application which is slimier to Smack.Both are UC client work on XMPP. But I am looking for a chatbot framework which can be integrate with these client . e.g. Windows bot framework can be integrate with skype,messanger etc.